# In SQL, how can I keep only the rows which occur after a row containing a certain value?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is my example dataset:

| zone_id | subzone_id | recency | operation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| p01 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| p01 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| p01 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| p01 | 1 | 4 | 1 |
| p01 | 1 | 5 | 0 |
| p01 | 1 | 6 | 1 |
| p01 | 1 | 7 | 1 |
| p02 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| p02 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| p02 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

What I'm trying to do is keep only the rows AFTER the most recent occurrence of any `operation` value of 0, as grouped by `zone_id` and `subzone_id`, where recency is indicated by the column of the same name (lowest value = most recent).

Therefore, in this example, the desired solution would return only these rows:

| zone_id | subzone_id | recency | operation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p01 | 1 | 6 | 1 |
| p01 | 1 | 7 | 1 |
| p02 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| p02 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

I know that I need to add some kind of indicator column that flags only those rows after the latest occurrence of a 0, and I have thought about various combinations of window functions to attempt this, but I am bashing my head against a wall trying to get it right.

Comment: Are you looking for a SELECT statement or a DELETE statement?

Comment: Why does (p02, 1) return anything? It does ***not*** follow a zero...

Comment: Which column(s) provide the ordering which (you think) exists here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the recency column `where recency is indicated by the column of the same name (lowest value = most recent)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the recency column is the order column, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: How can we order the final 3 rows of the sample data?  There are two records both having `recency` 0.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen they're two different partitions. `as grouped by zone_id and subzone_id`

Comment: @MatBailie it's a SELECT really, sorry for not specifying that.

You're right, (p02, 1) does not follow a zero. So I should have phrased the requirement as, keep all rows EXCEPT those which have operation = 0 or occur before the latest operation = 0 (if an operation = 0 exists)

Comment: In your question you said "rows after the latest occurrence of a 0" but in your last comment you've said "occur before the latest operation = 0". Can I suggest that you edit your question to clearly state what the requirements are and ensure that your sample data/results reflects this. Having clarifications/changes to the question scattered across comments makes it very difficult to understand what the current version of your question actually is

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  t.*
FROM
  your_table   AS t
WHERE
  t.recency > (
    SELECT IFNULL(MAX(recency), -1)
      FROM your_table
     WHERE zone_id = t.zone_id
       AND subzone_id = t.subzone_id
       AND operation = 0
  )
```

Or...

```
WITH
  augmented AS
(
  SELECT * FROM your_table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    zone_id, subzone_id, -1, 0
  FROM
    your_table
  GROUP by
    zone_id, subzone_id
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  augmented
QUALIFY
  recency
  >
  FIRST_VALUE(recency)
    OVER (
      PARTITION BY zone_id, subzone_id 
          ORDER BY operation, recency DESC
    )
```